# Confusion in selecting relay while designing pcb in eagle

Tags: pcb, relay, eaglecad

This is the first time I am designing a PCB in `Eagle`. Everything is going great but the problem I am facing is selecting `relay` in eagle library. All the relays in eagle are actually not the size I am looking for. I am planning to use [these](http://3.imimg.com/data3/VM/HG/MY-1844129/pcb-power-relay-250x250.jpg) relays but these type of relays are not available in eagle. Main point here is the shape of the relays available in eagle are of rectangular and I want to use some square one's. Can anyone help me or am I missing some library .?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're going to need to [create your own footprint](http://my.ece.msstate.edu/faculty/reese/senior_design/pcb/eagle/eagle_footprint_tutorial.pdf) in Eagle.  You can find the device measurements in the [datasheets](http://www.sproboticworks.com/assests/shop/IC%20datasheets/12v%2010a%20relay.pdf) for one of those parts.  If you have access to a printer you can print off a 1:1 representation of your footprint to make sure the part will actually fit in the footprint you design.  That will save you from having to wait several weeks for your boards to show up only to find out that your parts won't fit.

Comment: you sure that these type of relay not available in eagle.?

Comment: No, but it's great practice to understand how to make your own.  I've encountered similar problems in a [board](https://www.oshpark.com/shared_projects/GHClFwEi) I recently made; generally I'd rather create my own footprint than spend more than a few minutes looking for one in a library.

Comment: Okay I'll definitely go for this option too.! Thanks

Comment: In my experience, you should create your own components and libraries anyway, even if Eagle does have a similar part. Being able to customize it the way you want it is so much better than using pre-existing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest creating your own footprint , but since this is your first PCB , I would suggest that you to stay away from it for the time being until you gain more experience.You can search for libraries on this site:
https://www.element14.com/community/community/eagle/eagle_cad_libraries?ICID=EAGLE-library-download